# Kernel config option CONFIG_VIRT_WIFI

Tags: kernel, wifi, module

So there's a module that is an virtual wifi device wrapper for ethernet controllers. The kernel option for building this module is `CONFIG_VIRT_WIFI`.

The typical use-case for this is for devs writing wifi code, without having to mess with real adapters on a real network. They can use wl to configure a bunch of virtual adapters and test on this completely internal virtual network. Pretty cool.

**Are there are any other use-cases for it ?**

Can I for example; in a vm, on which the actual wifi adapter is wrapped in a virtual ethernet driver and then connected to a virtual switch which then gives you access to a real network... Could it be possible to wrap that in one of these virtual wifi wrappers and actually connect to a real wifi network ?

realwifi(ath0) -> virteth(eth0) on vm1 - virtwifi (wlan0) on vm1 -> connect to AP.

I'm guessing the answer is no. And if possible it would be ridiculously slow, or something.